# I can self host a REST server in WCF. Can I also self host a full asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

.NET 4.5/4.6, Visual Studio 2015, Windows Server 2016

I see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alikl/2010/06/04/walkthrough-build-host-and-test-simple-restful-wcf-service/), and elsewhere, that to self host (e.g. in an exe, without using IIS) a REST service, I can do that no problem. We like this because it simplifies deployment to get IIS out of the picture.

I also have a large asp.net application.

The question: Can I move the big asp.net app into a self hosted WCF application also? (for the same reason, to move to xcopy deploy and get IIS out of the picture).

Comment: Only if your web application is based on asp.net core which can be self host as a console application, otherwise it is not possible because asp.net applications rely on IIS for hosting

Comment: Only WCF/Web API/SignalR supports self hosting. If you use WebForms/MVC, you cannot self host, but bundle a web server, such as Cassini. Of course, if you switch completely to ASP.NET Core, you can self host again.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not self host ASP.Net web application built using .Net framework, you can host it only using IIS server. Though if your application is built using .Net Core framework, you might be able to self host it.